# What kind of fish are available and what is their effect?

Tags: torchlight-2

In Torchlight 2 you can go fishing in special places, but which kind of fish can you get? I am also particular interested in understanding which fish gives to your pet the most powerful transformation and what damage bonus get from them.

Answer (score 6):

According to the list on the [Torchlight wikia](http://torchlight.wikia.com/wiki/Fish_%28T2%29):

### Fish sizes

> **Normal -** Transform for 5 minutes
>
> **"Big"** - Transform for 15 minutes
>
> **"Giant" -** Transform permanently, until another fish is consumed. If this is a non-permanent fish/egg, then after that one expires your
>   pet is transformed back into its original form.

### Fish Types

> **Jackal Bass -** Transform into a Jackalbeast.
>
> **Largemouth Bass -** Transform into a Mimic.
>
> **Warsnout -** Transform into a Warbeast.
>
> **Tunnel Shark -** Transform into a Molebeast.
>
> **Web Fish -** Transform into a Spider.
>
> **Flying Fish -** Transform into a Swampflyer.
>
> **Bonefish -** Transform into a Torso.
>
> **Crab Egg -** Transform into a Crab Warrior.
>
> **Vampiric Spider Egg -** Transform into a Vampiric Spider.

### Transformation effects

> **[Jackalbeast](http://torchlight.wikia.com/wiki/Jackalbeast):** Increase poison armour by ~100% and grants a small amount of poison damage.
>
> **[Warbeast](http://torchlight.wikia.com/wiki/Warbeast):** Increases base average damage by ~85%.
>
> **Spider:**  Grants immobilizing web attack.
>
> **Mimic:**
>
> - +25% physical armour
> - +66% elemental armour
> - +50% HP
> - +33% damage (base)
> - +90% Interrupt Resistance
>
> **Molebeast:** 20% chance to Stun target for 3 seconds
>
> **Swampflyer:** +33% Attack Speed
>
> **Torso:**
>
> - +20% damage
> - +60% elemental
> - +25% HP (base)
> - Shreds armour
>
> **Crab Warrior:**
>       - +100% physical armour
>       - +100% elemental armour (base)
>
> **Vampiric Spider:**
>       - Attacks steal life for you.

### Other fish (direct effect on pet, or misc.)

> **Frenzy Fish -** For 5 minutes gain:
>    - 33% Faster Movement
>    - +33% Attack Speed
>
> **Gold Fish -** Not pet food. Just sell it.
>
> **Prismatic Morey -** For 5 minutes gain the following:
>    - +25 Critical Hit Chance
>    - +100% to Fire Damage
>    - +100% to Poison Damage
>    - +100% to Ice Damage
>    - +100% to Electric Damage

Comment: Is there any way to revert a permanent transformation? Say, for example, I fed my adorable badger a Giant Muckfish. What can I do to get him back to his badgery goodness?

Comment: You could try giving him a fish that confers a 3 minute transformation and see if he returns to his original form at the end of the 3 minutes.

Comment: Just tested this with Giant Crab Egg, then Jackal Bass. It transformed into Jackalbeast all right. After 5 minutes expired, it transformed back into original pet type. So, the permanent thing is not that permanent. See notes in the reply above.